# org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull instead of javax.annotation.Nonnull when implement method in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, java-annotations

After recent JetBrains Intellij IDEA updates I found out that when I'm trying to implement method annotated with javax.annotation.Nonnull - IDE implements it with org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull instead.

Example:

If you have an interface:

```java
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

interface User {

    @Nonnull
    String getName();
}
```

it will be implemented as:

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

class Customer implements User {

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

The question is how to configure IDE to implement methods with strict validation annotation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like a defect (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253324) although there is a workaround exist:
[Inspections > Java > Probable bugs > Nullability problems > @NotNull/@Nullable problems > Configure Annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMrdN.png). Set `javax.annotation.Nullable/javax.annotation.Nonnull` as defaults and restart the IDE.

Comment: My problem is when I try to run with gradle via command line. Not with the IDE. So this seems to have no affect for me.

Answer (score 4):

To add the library with annotations to a Gradle project, add the implementation [`org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations) dependency to the `build.gradle` file.